# Wrapping a Rust struct in a C++ class

Tags: rust

I would like to wrap a Rust struct in a C++ class.

Rust:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct RustStruct {
  num: i32,
  // other members..
}

pub extern "C" fn update(rust_struct: *mut RustStruct) {
  (*rust_struct).num = 1i32;
}

extern "C" {
  void update(void*);
}
```

C++:

```
class Wrapper {
  public:
    Wrapper();
    // ..

  private:
    void* rustStruct;
    // ..
};

Wrapper::Wrapper() {
  update(rustStruct); // crash
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Testing..";
}
```

I understand why this wouldn't work. My question is: how can I achieve what I'm basically trying to do (wrap a rust struct in a c++ class)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a mix of multiple FFIs concepts in your answer, so first let me recommend that your read the [Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html).

There are two ways to achieve what you wish, you can either:

- use a POD `struct` (Plain Old Data), aka C-compatible struct
- use an opaque pointer (`void*` in C)

Mixing them, as you did, does not make sense.

---

> Which to pick?

Both solutions have advantages and disadvantages, it's basically an expressiveness versus performance trade-off.

On the one hand, opaque pointers are more expressive: they can point to any Rust type. However:

- they require dynamic memory allocation
- they require being manipulated by Rust functions (so always indirectly from C or C++)

On the other hand, POD struct do not require either of those, but they are limited to only a subset of types expressible in Rust.

---

> How to use a POD?

This is the easiest, actually, so let's start with it!

In Rust:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct RustStruct {
    num: i32,
    // other members, also PODs!
}
```

In C++

```
struct RustStruct {
    int32_t num;
    // other members, also with Standard Layout
    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout
};

class Wrapper {
public:
private:
    RustStruct rustStruct;
};
```

Note that I just got along with your question stricto censu here, you could actually merge the two in a single C++ class:

```
class RustStruct {
public:
private:
    int32_t num;
    // other members, also with Standard Layout
    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout
};
```

Just avoid `virtual` methods.

---

> How to use an opaque pointer?

This gets trickier:

- Only the Rust code may correctly create/copy/destruct the type
- Beware of leaking...

So, we need to implement a lot of functions in Rust:

```
#![feature(box_raw, box_syntax)]
use std::boxed;

pub struct RustStruct {
    num: i32,
    // other members, anything goes
}

pub extern "C" fn createRustStruct() -> *mut RustStruct {
    boxed::into_raw(box RustStruct::new())
}

pub extern "C" fn destroyRustStruct(o: *mut RustStruct) {
    boxed::from_raw(o);
}
```

Alright... now on to C++:

```
struct RustStruct;

RustStruct* createRustStruct();
void destroyRustStruct(RustStruct*);

class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(): rustStruct(RustStructPtr(createRustStruct())) {}

private:
    struct Deleter {
        void operator()(RustStruct* rs) const {
            destroyRustStruct(rs);
        }
    };

    typedef std::unique_ptr<RustStruct, Deleter> RustStructPtr;

    RustStructPtr rustStruct;
}; // class Wrapper
```

So, yes, a bit more involved, and `Wrapper` is not copyable either (copy has to be delegated to Rust too). Anyway, this should get you started!

*Note: if you have a lot of opaque pointers to wrap, a templated C++ class taking the copy/destroy functions as template parameters could alleviate a lot of boiler plate.*

Comment: `box RustStruct::new()` without feature flag? Has `box` syntax been made stable?

Comment: @VladimirMatveev not yet, they must be missing a flag